# Travis-ci doesn't display organization's repo

Tags: settings, travis-ci, github-third-party-apps

I was able to give travis-ci a permission to access my github organization (like [this](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/setting-up-and-managing-organ%5B%E2%80%A6%5Dizations-and-teams/approving-oauth-apps-for-your-organization)).

But when I go to **travis-ci** settings, it is still telling me `You are not currently a member of any organization`
[image]

Which is wrong because if I go to my **github** setting, travis-ci shows me it has access to the organization.

[image]

What I tried:

- sign out then sign in again (like proposed [here](https://travis-ci.community/t/organization-repositories-gone/5938)): NOT WORKING
- clear browser cookies (like proposed [here](https://travis-ci.community/t/clicking-on-login-with-github-on-travis-ci-org-fails-with-state-mismatch/5872/3)): NOT WORKING TOO

Any other idea to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the org owner gave travis-ci permission to access the org, I still need to do this step:

- publicize my membership ([see community discussion](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2519#issuecomment-89550325), [check how to](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/publicizing-or-hiding-organization-membership))

Meaning:

- the org owner invites you to be part of the org.
- you accept the invitation & make sure to switch your visibility to `public`

Now I can see the org from travis-ci
[image]